# Triangulate set of 3D points

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry, computer-vision, triangulation

I have a set of Points [X, Y, Z]
as an interest points of a 3D Object

and I'm searching for an algorithm that used to convert this points into 3D-Model "Triangulation Algorithm"

I just tried "Delaunay Triangulations" algorithm, but its result is the convex hull of my set of points
**and this will not work for me as all inner points will be neglected**

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Delaunay triangulation in 3D produces a partition of the convex hull into tetrahedra, with all your points becoming vertices of the tetrahedra. Inner points will not be "neglected."
Here is an image from the [CGAL manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20131013182650/http://www.cgal.org:80/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_3/Chapter_main.html):

 
[image]